# ERROR: type "geoms" does not exist. What version of pgRouting should I use for postgres 8.4 & postgis 1.5?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I am running this on windows 7:

Postgres 8.4
postgis 1.5

I installed pgrouting, but I am getting the error: ERROR: type "geoms" does not exist.

so my question is: which version of pgRouting should I use?

I suppose I should use this one : http://www.wiesenhaan.com/pgrouting/pgRouting-1.03_pg-8.4.2.zip

If the version number is accurate, what other possible causes for such error?

thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

`ERROR: type "geoms" does not exist.` is not a pgRouting error, I think. Are you able to use PostGIS functions?

Comment: I think I figured out where the error is. Dijkstra_sp get executed in postgres without any problem. However the error seems to appear in Java. I assume I need to install a driver that identifies "geoms" data type.